# Nested JSON convert to CSV Dataweave

Tags: json, csv, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

```
{
    "one": {
        "two": [
             "199052",
            "109926"
        
         
        ],
        "three": [
            "191",
            "190",
            "189",
            "188",
            "187"
       
        ],
        "four": {
            "five": [
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-18"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-14"
                },
                {
                    "five": "2022-03-14"
                },
            
            ],
            "six": {
                "seven": [
                   "Test1",
                    "Test2",
                     "Test1",
                    "Test2"
       
                ],
                "eight": [
                   "first description.",
                    "second description",
                     "first description.",
                    "second description"
                  
                ]
            },
            "nine": {
                "name": [
                     "Ps3564",
                    "35355Ps"
                 
       
           
                ]
            },
            "tenCreated": [
                
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                },
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                },
                {
                    "tenCreated": "2022-02-10"
                }
            ],
            "elevenUpdated": [
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
                {
                    "elevenUpdated": "2022-03-24"
                },
            ],
            "twelve": {
                "thirteen": [
                    "fourteen",
                    "Do",
                    "Do again",
                    "Do work",
                    "Doone"

                ]
            },
            "fifteen": {
                "name": [
                   "Good",
                    "Not good",
                    "good"
              
                ]
            },
            "sixteen": {
                "sixteenCreator": [
                  "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan kowalski",
                     "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan kowalski"
        
                ],
                "seventeen": null
            },
            "eieighteen": [
               "Test test",
                "test test 10",
                "api test",
         
             
                
            ],
            "ninteen": {
                "ninteeneReporter": [
                  "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski"
                  
                    
                ],
                "twentyEmail": [
                "jankowalski@",
                    "jankowalski@"
              
                ]
            },
            "twentyOne": {
                "TwentyTwo": [
                "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski",
                    "Jan Kowalski"
                   
                
                ],
                "TwnetyThree": [
                   "jankowalski@",
                    "jankowalski@"
                 
                ]
            },
            "TwentyFour": {
                "TwentyFive": [
                    "P186",
                    "P186",
                    "P186",
                 
                ],
                "TwentySix": {
                    "TwentySeven": [
                        "Plan",
                        "Plan",
                        "Plan"
                     
             
                    ],
                    "TwentyEight": [
                         "END",
                        "END"
                 
                    ],
                    "Thiry": [
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                        "To Do",
                  
                    ],
                    "ThirtyOne": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi I have this json and I would like convert it to CSV.
And here is my transform  DateTime I did something like this but this code give me extra tag for each date.

```
"five": {
    "five": payload.one.four.five map (item, index) -> {
    five : item
     as DateTime 
     {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"}
      as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} }
```

But my output for this data looks like this. There is only the DATE. It's a possible to change the DATE without change the structure like I did?

```
"five": [
                "2022-03-24T15:17:46.846+0100",
                "2022-03-24T09:05:35.133+0100",
                "2022-03-24T09:06:12.081+0100",
 
            ],
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Please provide a detailed explanation and examples.

Comment: Note that neither your input nor your script are valid.

Answer (score 0):

If your expected output is a CSV with only the dates under column `five` then you could just select it:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.one.four.five
```

Output (after removing the extra double quote in line 17 of the input):

```
five
2022-03-24
2022-03-24
2022-03-18
2022-03-18
2022-03-18
2022-03-14
2022-03-14
```

If you want an extra transformation of the data, you can map each element of the array as needed:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.one.four.five 
        map (item, index) -> {five: item.five as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}
```